# What is the right way to mock and unmock 'node-fetch' module in Node.js using Jest and Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

**Testing function**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

class Services () {
    someFunc() {
       const data = await fetch(dummy url);
       // business logic
    }
    anotherFunc() {
       const data = await fetch(dummy url);
       // business logic
    }
}

export default new Service();
```

**Actual testing**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
jest.mock('node-fetch', () => jest.fn());

beforeEach(() => {
    mocked(fetch).mockClear();
})

 describe('test first method', () => {
        it('should fetch some data without mock fetch', async () => {
            const data = await service.someFunc();
            expect(data).toHaveProperty('items');
        })
    })

  describe('test second method', () => {
        it('should return data with mock fetch', async () => {
            mocked(fetch).mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject());
            const data = await service.anotherFunc();
            expect(data).toHaveProperty('items');
        })
    })
```

At this moment I have a problem with the fetch functions in the first describe case and get **" TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"**. So I need a mocked version of fetch only in the second describe case. In the first describe case it should use fetch without mock function replacement.

How I can fix it? Will be grateful for the assist.

Comment: How exactly does service use fetch? If it uses it by importing from node-fetch, it cannot be unmocked because service is already forced to use mocked module, it needs to be reimported per test with jest.isolateModules or else. You generally need to have mocked fetch in all tests because real requests shouldn't be performed in unit tests.

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you for the answer. Yeah, you are right, can you please write how to use jest.isolateModules in case of my pseudocode. Because the documentation poor for example, and I think that tried everything manually.

Comment: The question is incomplete, and the solution depends on it. Please, show how exactly node-fetch is used. Again, you shouldn't perform real requests in unit tests, this is most likely XY problem.

Comment: Yeah sure, I have updated the question body.

Comment: @RobertoCarlos - have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock?